# View cell binding causes crash when removing an element on android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing an issue where if I give my frame that is inside of a ListView's item template that when I delete an object I get a FrameRenderer exception, specifically `Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FrameRenderer`.  However, on iOS this is not a problem. If I set a static value for the corner radius, the error goes away.

The reason for why I need to have the view model control the frame radius is that we are trying to create circles, and we've noticed that in order to achieve a circle android has to have a corner radius twice of its width and radius. SO if W=R=20 then the corner radius is 40. For iOS it is the reverse, the corner radius is half.

XAML where it is being bound:

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <customcontrols:NoHighlightCell>
                                        <StackLayout effects:RoundCornersEffect.CornerRadius="8" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5">
                                                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{Binding SelectedColor}"></BoxView>
                                                <StackLayout Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" Padding="5, 5, 0, 5" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{Binding CellBackgroundColor}">
                                                    <Frame Padding="0" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadiusForPhone}"  BackgroundColor="{Binding InitialCircleColor}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" HasShadow="False">
                                                        <Label Padding="0" Text="{Binding UserInitials}" TextColor="{Binding LetterColoring}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                                    </Frame>
                                                    <StackLayout Spacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                                                            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding FullName}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Location}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                        <customcontrols:UnderlineLabel TextDecorations="Underline" Padding="0, 0, 14, 0" Text="Remove" TextColor="#BB3734" FontSize="13" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding ManagingUsers}">
                                                            <customcontrols:UnderlineLabel.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveUserCommand, Source={x:Reference root}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                                            </customcontrols:UnderlineLabel.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        </customcontrols:UnderlineLabel>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                    </customcontrols:NoHighlightCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

The `CornerRadiusForPhone` code in its view model:

```
 public float CornerRadiusForPhone {
            get {
                if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    return 80f;
                } else
                {
                    return 20f;
                }
            } 
        }
```

Part of the code that causes the crash is in the view model associated with the XAML which simply deletes the selected item from the `Users` ObservableCollection which is the List's ItemSource.

```
private void RemoveUser(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        var toRemove = (RegisteredUsersViewModel) obj;
        tokenService.Logout(toRemove.UserId);
        Users.Remove(toRemove);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e);
    }

}
```

Normally I would prefer to use OnPlatform inside of the xaml, but unless I am mistaken, since CornerRadius is a float and there is no type argument of float, I cannot use that trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I am still not sure why I cannot use that type of binding, I did realize that CornerRadius is apparently of type Single when doing the OnPlatform. This is odd as if you go to its definition it is clearly a float type. Regardless, here is the solution

```
<Frame.CornerRadius>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single" iOS="20" Android="80"/>
</Frame.CornerRadius>
```

This does the same thing as what my initial binding was supposed to do, but without the negative effect of causing a crash due to a frame render issue

Comment: Can't accept my own answer until tomorrow (4/4/2020)